# jQuery fancyform only works on first element

Tags: jquery, forms, loops, styles, fancyform

using this script to style forms: http://lutrasoft.nl/jQuery/fancyform/

My site generates the forms dynamically in smarty and the jQuery is only working the first select element so how can I make it work on both?

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
{literal}
$("#select").transformSelect();
{/literal}
</script>
```

This is what I tried but still only works on the first element

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
{literal}
$("#select").each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.transformSelect();
});
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using the same id for both of your elements? If so it wont work. Change your ID to class and your sjquery selector.

Comment: Yes am using an ID, just changed it to class and now it's working, thank you my friend.

Comment: instead of class you can also use : `$("select").transformSelect();` if you want all select tags to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this. It will affect all the select boxes without requiring ID or Class

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
   {literal}
   $(":select").each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.transformSelect();
   });
   {/literal}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#select").each(function() {` look likes you have multiple select with the same ID..**(ID SHOULD ALWAYS BE UNIQUE)**

change it to class..and \try this

```
 $(".select").each(function() {
```